# How to import android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat.Builder class in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to implement simple notifications in my android app. I am reffering this [developer guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

**But getting this error message :**

```
Incompatible types.
Required: android.support.v7app.NotificationCompat.Builder
Found: android.support.v4.app.Notification.Compat.Builder
```

[Error Message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBG5r.png)

**For the following code snippet :**

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle("My notification")
                        .setContentText("Hello World!");
```

**Here are my imports :**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
```

I think the correct `NotificationCompat` class is imported. I am using `Android Studio v2.1.2` for development. Please help me with this error message. I am new to android programming and java.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The return type of those builder methods are returning the v4 version of NotificationCompat.Builder. The v7 NotificationCompat.Builder extends the v4 version and largely just inherits the methods from it, meaning the return types don't change.

Documentation:

- [v4](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html)
- [v7](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html)

If you need the v7 version (for the support of NotificationCompat.MediaStyle), just cast to it.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = (android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("My notification")
                    .setContentText("Hello World!");
```

If not, swap your imports to use the v4 version.

Comment: Your documentation link for v7 is broken - it just goes to an index which has an entry for the v4 NotificationCompat, and also an entry that looks like it should be for the v7 NotificationCompat but actually just links back to the same index...

Answer (score 43):

Replace

```
 import android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat;
```

with

```
 import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
```

Comment: Going from support lib 26 to 27 this caused a bit headache. This solution nails it

Comment: As far as I can tell there is no import android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat; where have you found that?

Comment: @Sobvan Exactly, I've been searching this package name at developer.android.com and there is no such thing

Answer (score 14):

Latest working solution 2020

If you have updated to Androidx then 
replace

```
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat
//or
import android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat
```

with

```
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
```